# ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, outlook, swt

I need to create a jsp page with a button - when clicked, it opens the New E-mail window in outlook with 'To', 'Subject', and 'Body' fields populated.

I am implementing this via servlet, so when user clicks the button, the servlet is called and the following code is called from doGet() of the servlet class.

This works fine when I try to tested it as an independent java application, and the new message window opens perfectly. But when I try to open it via the jsp form, I am getting the exception.

Exception :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
```

I have included the following jars :

```
org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.7.0.v3735b.jar
org.eclipse.core.commands_3.6.0.I20110111-0800.jar
```

Code referred from : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMicrosoftIntegration/article.html

Code :

```
Display display = Display.getCurrent();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
OleFrame frame = new OleFrame(shell, SWT.NONE);
// This should start outlook if it is not running yet
OleClientSite site = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "OVCtl.OVCtl");
site.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE);
// now get the outlook application
OleClientSite site2 = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE,"Outlook.Application");
OleAutomation outlook = new OleAutomation(site2);
OleAutomation mail = invoke(outlook, "CreateItem", 0 /* Mail item */)
        .getAutomation();
setProperty(mail, "To", "someone@something.com"); /*
                           * Empty but could also be
                           * predefined
                           */
// setProperty(mail, "Bcc", "test@gmail.com"); 
/*
                           * Empty but could also be
                           * predefined
                           */
setProperty(mail, "BodyFormat", 2 /* HTML */);
setProperty(mail, "Subject", "Top News for you");
        setProperty(mail, "HtmlBody",
            "some message");
//      File file = new File("c:/temp/test.txt");
//      if (file.exists()) {
//        OleAutomation attachments = getProperty(mail, "Attachments");
//        invoke(attachments, "Add", "c:/temp/test.txt");
//      } else {
//        MessageDialog
//            .openInformation(shell, "Info",
//                "Attachment File c:/temp/test.txt not found; will send email with attachment");
//      }
invoke(mail, "Display" /* or "Send" */);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using jars in web application in java, you have put the jar files in the `lib` folder in the project. So please make sure you do that.

Comment: Tried adding in web-inf/lib folder, still not working.